# LINQ Filter values on list values using contain

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I know that there are several SO posts on this matter and I have used them when coming up with my current solution.

Looking at the 4 rows of code below, the first three are not working but the forth one is (!?) and I do not understand why that is. The first two only checks against a single string: "Where values that contains 'string'", and the later two checks values against a list of strings "Where values that contain any of the strings in this list"

```
contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => cdr.Firstname.Contains(firstName)).ToList();
contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => cdr.Lastname.Contains(lastName)).ToList();

contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => accountIdsList.Any(ail => cdr.AccountId.Contains(ail))).ToList();
contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => contactIdsList.Any(cil => cdr.ContactId.Contains(cil))).ToList();
```

My goal is to filter the list depending on the search filters entered into the function. Below is the error I get, which makes me think there is something about the `contactsDynamicResponses.Values` that is the problem here, but I am lost.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> Project.Entities.Contact.Models.Dynamics.ContactDynamicsResponse.Firstname.get returned null.

How the rows look completely:

```
contactsDynamicResponses.Values = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ? contactsDynamicResponses.Values : contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => cdr.Firstname.Contains(firstName)).ToList();
contactsDynamicResponses.Values = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) ? contactsDynamicResponses.Values : contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => cdr.Lastname.Contains(lastName)).ToList();
           
contactsDynamicResponses.Values = accountIdsList == null ? contactsDynamicResponses.Values : contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => accountIdsList.Any(ail => cdr.AccountId.Contains(ail))).ToList();
contactsDynamicResponses.Values = contactIdsList == null ? contactsDynamicResponses.Values : contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => contactIdsList.Any(cil => cdr.ContactId.Contains(cil))).ToList();
```

Any thoughts are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Seems you should add null-checks before calling `Contains` on `FirstName` and `LastName` because these properties can get null and cause your exception here

Comment: The exception already tells you exactly what the problem is: `ContactDynamicsResponse.Firstname.get returned null.`. So Firstname is null and you are calling `.Contains()` on a string which is null so therefore you get a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add null-checks in the query:

```
contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr => cdr.Firstname != null && 
    cdr.Firstname.Contains(firstName)).ToList();
```

The exception says that `FirstName` is null.
Also add this check in the other queries, for example for `LastName`

Comment: Aaah, of course! It didn't occur to me that cdr.FirstName could be null (even though it was spelled out). Thank you for making my day :)

Answer (score 0):

**A shorter way to do a null-check:**

```cs
contactsDynamicResponses.Values.Where(cdr =>
    cdr.Firstname?.Contains(firstName) == true
).ToList();
```

It looks a bit odd with the `== true` but that is because the result of the comparison is `bool?`